# list git/stash pull requests for branch

Tags: git, bitbucket, bamboo, bitbucket-server

I am working on a full Atlassian suite, jira stash/git and bamboo.

Does anyone know if there a way to list the PR's for my current branch?

I need to get find out from shell if my current branch has an open PR and find it's ID if one exists. No need to create a pr, as this will be done by the dev. 
Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: As PR would be a repository hosting feature, I believe Git could not be able to realize that. Maybe with some third party tool or addon

Comment: Did you look at the stash API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Stash' (or Bitbucket's) REST API to get information about the pullrequests for a repository:

- [Stash GET pull-requests](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/stash/latest/stash-rest.html#idp29120)
- [Bitbucket GET pull-requests](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/bitbucket-server/latest/bitbucket-rest.html#idp2969808)

That way you can implement your own script (bash with [curl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/curl.1.html), java, groovy, python, ...) to get the info you need.

General info about the REST APIs is available [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/stash/docs/latest/reference/rest-api.html).

Comment: For some reason, REST API doesn't work for branches with / in name

Comment: @kingoleg Did you try encoding the / to %2F ?

Comment: @WillSheppard I didn't

Comment: None of these links survived.

Answer (score 12):

Get the open pull requests from Bitbucket/Stash using:

```
$ git fetch origin 'refs/pull-requests/*:refs/remotes/origin/pull-requests/*'
```

Check the pull-requests that are on the current branch:

```
$ git branch --all --contains
  remotes/origin/pull-requests/31/from
  remotes/origin/pull-requests/31/merge
```

Clean up with:

```
$ git remote prune origin
```

Answer (score 2):

There's the commercial BobSwift of commercial CLI addons for the entire Atlassian suite.

For [Bitbucket](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/SCLI) there's: `getPullRequest` and get `PullRequestList`.

I think it's $10 for 1-10 users, in line with the usual "get people hooked" pricing policy for small and indie dev shops.